# Как добавить значения из textBox в listView (при генерации значений)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Подскажите, как при генерации GUID добавлять значения из `textBox1` и `textBox2` в `listView1`, где `columnHeader1` должно принять значение от `textBox1`, а `columnHeader2` значение от `textBox2`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создание и генерация GUID происходит следующим образом:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox2.Text != "")
        {
            key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\001").CreateSubKey(textBox1.Text = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("B"));
            key.SetValue("text", textBox2.Text, RegistryValueKind.ExpandString);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Properties.Settings.Default.SaveGUID))
            {
                Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\001", true).DeleteSubKey(Properties.Settings.Default.SaveGUID, false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть свойство items. Это элемент списка(1 столбец). У него есть свойство Items остальные столбцы (второй, третий и т.д.).

```
ListBoxItem item = new ListBoxItem("текст первого столбца");
item.Items.Add("текст второго столбца");
listView1.Items.Add(item);
```